# How to use VLC as a screencast software?

Tags: vlc, screencast

As far as I am aware, VLC can record from the desktop source. This could make VLC a potential tool for screencast recording. However, I am failing to use it properly for this purpose. Remaining questions:

- How can I change the rotation of the recorded screencast?
- How can I record screencasts with and without sound (internal and/or external source)?
- How can I record only a screen selection or specific window?

Is someone knowledgeable enough with VLC to outline the use of VLC for screencast recording under consideration of the aforementioned questions?